# Can the verb "прозябать" actually be perfectivized?

Tags: глаголы, вид

I recently came across the verb **прозябать** in a book. Its meaning is one of *eking out an existence* in the sense of enduring hardship and suffering instead of truly living. This to me, is an ongoing state, which I interpret as purely imperfective in any imaginable context. However, Wiktionary offers the perfective partner **прозябнуть**, and I'm hard put to imagine a context in which one could perfectivize an ongoing state of being such as this *unless* it can perhaps also refer to the *onset* of said state. Is this proposed perfective actually valid and in use or is Wiktionary just being exhaustive?

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/982306 - ПРОЗЯ́БНУТЬ, прозябну, прозябнешь, прош. вр. прозяб, прозябла, совер.
1. (несовер. прозябать). Сильно озябнуть (разг.). «Лошади, прозябнув, не стояли на месте.» Пушкин. «Прозябли вы - согреем вас.» Грибоедов.
2. Произрасти (устар.).

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/339266

Comment: @άνθρωπος So, if I understood correctly, the perfective прозябнуть can mean to get really cold. In other words, in the example above, the horses got really cold and couldn't became restless? And in the second, "Your chilled (to the bone) — let's get you warmed up." Right?

Comment: Прозябли - что-то среднее между окоченели и озябли. Озяб - это когда, это когда замерз сверху, кожа замёрзла - её достаточно растереть, чтобы согреть. Прозябли - это когда холод проник глубже. А окоченеть, когда пропадает чувствительность в мышцах и возникают проблемы с движением. Озяб<прозяб<продрог<окоченел. Зяб~озноб - дрожь от холода или чего еще, зябнуть - слегка дрожать от холода. Приставка про- дает увеличение действия - ехать-проехать.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Спасибо огромное за разъяснение! Я все понял. Самый интересно то, что в английском также можно сказать **chill(ed)**, когда достаточно растереть, и **chilled *through*** (т.е. буквально "про"), когда холод проник глужбе. Буду знать!))

Answer (score 3):

The original meaning of *прозябать*, now dated, is "to sprout, to grow, to vegetate (of a plant)". The modern meaning is a metaphor, meaning "to live a vegetable life".

In this dated meaning it does form the perfective:

> - Тут прежние буйные потехи, карты, насмешки, кощунства развеяли эти начатки размышления, но не совершенно; семя было брошено и силилось прозябнуть. *[Н. И. Греч. Черная женщина (1834)]*
> - — Весь ваш! весь к услугам молодого поколения! — продолжал между тем хозяин, усаживая Веригина в покойное кресло и потчуя его дорогой сигарой, — ведь вы наша надежда, вы зерно, из которого должен прозябнуть и процвести первый побег нашего особного, нашего народного самовозрастия! *[М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Тихое пристанище (1857-1865)]*

But, as you mentioned, the metaphorical meaning doesn't lend itself to the perfective naturally.

The perfective verb has another meaning (or homonym), "to freeze, to chill through" (linguists disagree on whether it's a development of the first meaning or a distant cognate). [A poem by Kozma Prutkov](https://www.culture.ru/poems/31191/pomeshik-i-sadovnik) plays on this homonymy:

> …
> Помещик о своем растенье вспоминает
> И так Ефима вопрошает:
> «Что? хорошо ль растенье прозябает?»
> «Изрядно, — тот в ответ, — прозябло уж совсем!»
>
> Пусть всяк садовника такого нанимает,
> Который понимает,
> Что значит слово «прозябает».

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! Also, in the second example, the perfective is used to delineate the end of the withering before the blossoming, correct?

Comment: @CocoPop: it means "from which the first sprout will have grown and blossomed", there is no withering.